how to generate video with video, images, audio and text file using ffmpeg
I want to generate video using video, audio, images and text. and there will be sequence for all the inputs. According to those sequence new generated video will play.
Like if, video1 - sequence1, video2 - sequence2, audio1 - sequence1, audio2 - sequence2, image1 - sequence3, image2 - sequence1, text1 - sequence1
then video will generate like this sequence.
video1 - audio1 - image2 - text1 - video2 - audio2 - image1
text will display on the screen when it is started video1.
I tried using this command:
$cmd = 'C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg '.
   '-i 658eb783703d5.mp4 '.
   '-i audio1.mp3 '.
   '-loop 1 -t 3 -i d3.jpg '.
   '-f lavfi -t 4 -i color=c=black:s=640x480 '.
   '-filter_complex "'.
   '[0:v]trim=duration=10[v0]; '.
   '[1:a]atrim=duration=5[a1]; '.
   '[2:v]trim=duration=3[v2]; '.
   '[3:v]drawtext=text=\'Hello World\':x=10:y=10:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white,format=yuv420p[v3]; '.
   '[v0][v2][v3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v]; '.
   '[a1]anull[a]" '.
   '-map "[v]" -map "[a]" video_convert/output.mp4';

$output = shell_exec($cmd);

But this generates only blank file. How can I do this?
Thank you.

I've done a similar thing in BASH.  I don't know powershell very well.
